# Parsing epoch milliseconds from json with Spark 2

Tags: json, parsing, apache-spark

Has anyone parsed a millisecond timestamp using `from_json` in Spark 2+? How's it done?

So [Spark changed](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10687/commits/600f73f385347d4a2ed8ca21f3268c01cd8855f7) the `TimestampType` to parse epoch numerical values as being in seconds instead of millis in v2.

My input is a hive table that has a json formatted string in a column which I'm trying to parse like this:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Problematic Timestamps")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("categoryId", LongType) ::
  StructField("cleared", BooleanType) ::
  StructField("dataVersion", LongType) ::
  StructField("details", DataTypes.createArrayType(StringType)) ::
  …
  StructField("timestamp", TimestampType) ::
  StructField("version", StringType) :: Nil
)
val item_parsed =
    spark.sql("select * FROM source.jsonStrInOrc")
    .select('itemid, 'locale,
            from_json('internalitem, schema)
                as 'internalitem,
            'version, 'createdat, 'modifiedat)
val item_flattened = item_parsed
    .select('itemid, 'locale,
            $"internalitem.*",
            'version as'outer_version, 'createdat, 'modifiedat)
```

This can parse a row with a column containing:

> {"timestamp": 1494790299549, "cleared": false, "version": "V1", "dataVersion": 2, "categoryId": 2641, "details": [], …}

And that gives me `timestamp` fields like `49338-01-08 00:39:09.0` from a value `1494790299549` which I'd rather read as: `2017-05-14 19:31:39.549`

Now I could set the schema for timestamp to be a long, then divide the value by 1000 and cast to a timestamp, but then I'd have `2017-05-14 19:31:39.000` not `2017-05-14 19:31:39.549`. I'm having trouble figuring out how I could either:

- Tell `from_json` to parse a *millisecond* timestamp (maybe by subclassing the TimestampType in some way to use in the schema)
- Use a `LongType` in the schema and cast that to a **Timestamp which preserves the milliseconds**.

### Addendum on UDFs

I found that trying to do the division in the select and then casting didn't look clean to me, though it's a perfectly valid method. I opted for a UDF that used a `java.sql.timestamp` which is actually specified in epoch milliseconds.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, from_json, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.
{BooleanType, DataTypes, IntegerType, LongType,
StringType, StructField, StructType, TimestampType}

val tsmillis = udf { t: Long => new Timestamp (t) }

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Problematic Timestamps")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("categoryId", LongType) ::
  StructField("cleared", BooleanType) ::
  StructField("dataVersion", LongType) ::
  StructField("details", DataTypes.createArrayType(StringType)) ::
  …
  StructField("timestamp", LongType) ::
  StructField("version", StringType) :: Nil
)
val item_parsed =
    spark.sql("select * FROM source.jsonStrInOrc")
    .select('itemid, 'locale,
            from_json('internalitem, schema)
                as 'internalitem,
            'version, 'createdat, 'modifiedat)
val item_flattened = item_parsed
    .select('itemid, 'locale,
            $"internalitem.categoryId", $"internalitem.cleared",
            $"internalitem.dataVersion", $"internalitem.details",
            tsmillis($"internalitem.timestamp"),
            $"internalitem.version",
            'version as'outer_version, 'createdat, 'modifiedat)
```

See how that's in the select.
I think it would be worthwhile to do a performance test to see if using `withcolumn` division and casting is faster than the `udf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I could set the schema for timestamp to be a long, then divide the value by 1000

Actually this exactly what you need, just keep the types right. Let's say you have only `Long` `timestamp` field:

```scala
val df = spark.range(0, 1).select(lit(1494790299549L).alias("timestamp"))
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timestamp: bigint]
```

If you divide by 1000:

```scala
val inSeconds = df.withColumn("timestamp_seconds", $"timestamp" / 1000)
// org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timestamp: bigint, timestamp_seconds: double]
```

you'll get timestamp in seconds as double (note that this is SQL, not Scala behavior).

All what is left is `cast` (**Spark < 3.1**)

```scala
inSeconds.select($"timestamp_seconds".cast("timestamp")).show(false)
// +-----------------------+
// |timestamp_seconds      |
// +-----------------------+
// |2017-05-14 21:31:39.549|
// +-----------------------+
```

or  (**Spark >= 3.1**) `timestamp_seconds` (or directly `timestamp_millis`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, timestamp_seconds}

inSeconds.select(timestamp_seconds($"timestamp_seconds")).show(false)

// +------------------------------------+
// |timestamp_seconds(timestamp_seconds)|
// +------------------------------------+
// |2017-05-14 21:31:39.549             |
// +------------------------------------+

df.select(expr("timestamp_millis(timestamp)")).show(false)
// +---------------------------+
// |timestamp_millis(timestamp)|
// +---------------------------+
// |2017-05-14 21:31:39.549    |
// +---------------------------+
```

Comment: Oh, so it's not rounding the division into another long? Great!